# Tooltip JS not being called in 'included' php files

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

i am calling a Header.php in main.php using

```
<head> </head>
<body>
<?php
 include 'common/header.php';
?>
</body>
```

In the Head i am calling all the CSS and JS. 
The CSS are being called in header.php properly.

In Header.php i have 2  tags. I would like to implement tooltip on one of them.

```
<li><a class="english" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" href="">English</a></li>
```

also i added the JS for tooltip

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}); 
</script>
```

I tried to add this above code in header.php , bottom of index.php and also in head of index.php.

If i try to create a tooltip in the main.php file , it works absolutely fine. 
there are no errors in console. I dont know what is the error. 
Help ! TIA.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded at all? Same question for the tooltip plugin...

Comment: there are no jQuery error.

Comment: @Capsule : yes the jquery is loaded.

Comment: Please provide snippets to understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code (`script` tag) at the bottom of `header.php` file, after all the html elements.

Comment: It would make no difference as the `$(function()` waits for the DOM to be loaded, it can be placed anywhere